# Oracle Client 11g for Solaris

Tags: solaris, oracle-11g

OS: solaris 11_2-text-x86

I want to install an Oracle Client but can only see the Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (SPARC) but my Solaris OS isn´t sparc. When i still install the sparc version (64 bit) i get this message:

```
./runInstaller: line 222: install/.oui: cannot execute [Invalid argument]
```

Is there any other version i overlook?

Thanks in advance